# Creating ordinal bar chart with DC.js and Angular 2

Tags: angular, d3.js, charts, dc.js

i have a problem with creating ordinal bar chart in angular 2 and dc.js i found this example in Javascript: https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/examples/ordinal-bar.html, but when i am trying to set property `.xUnits` i get an error:

> TypeError: _x.rangeBands is not a function
>       at prepareXAxis (dc.js:3256)
>       at drawChart (dc.js:3919)
>       at Object._chart._doRender (dc.js:3898)
>       at Object._chart.render [as _render] (dc.js:1691)
>       at Object.render (dc.js:5586)
>       at StatisticDcComponent.ngAfterViewInit (statistic-dc.component.ts:63)
>       at callProviderLifecycles (core.es5.js:11189)
>       at callElementProvidersLifecycles (core.es5.js:11164)
>       at callLifecycleHooksChildrenFirst (core.es5.js:11148)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12253)

this is my component:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit  } from '@angular/core';
import { CsvService } from 'angular2-json2csv';

import * as d3 from 'd3';
import * as crossfilter from 'crossfilter2';
import { DSVRowString } from 'd3';
import * as dc from 'dc';


import { StatisticService } from '../statistic/statistic.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'statisticdc',
  styleUrls: ['./statistic-dc.scss'],
  templateUrl: './statistic-dc.html'
})
export class StatisticDcComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  xdomain: any[];
  ydomain: any[];
  csvSample: any;
  experiments: any;

  constructor(private statisticService: StatisticService, private csvservice: CsvService) {

  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    let that = this;
    this.csvSample = this.csvservice.ConvertToCSV(this.statisticService.getDealers());
    let chart = dc.barChart('#test');
    this.experiments = d3.csvParse(this.csvSample);
    let exper = [];

    this.experiments.forEach(function(x) {
      exper.push(x);
    });

    let ndx = crossfilter(exper);

    let runDimension = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d['dealer_name']; });
    let speedSumGroup = runDimension.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return d['total_bonus_num']; });

    chart
    .width(768)
    .height(380)
    .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
    .x(d3.scaleOrdinal())
    .brushOn(false)
    .xAxisLabel('Fruit')
    .yAxisLabel('Quantity Sold')
    .dimension(runDimension)
    .barPadding(0.1)
    .outerPadding(0.05)
    .group(speedSumGroup);

    chart.render();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }
}
```

Maybe anyone knows how to solve this problem or where i can find documentation for Dc.js and Angular2+ ?

Comment: Looks like you are attempting to use dc.js with d3 version 4. So far it's only compatible with d3v3.

Comment: @Gordon maybe you know for some alternative for dc.js, that works with d3v4 and crossfilter?

Comment: None that I know of. Best workaround currently is to include both d3v3 and d3v4 in your page, but change the symbol name of one or the other (or use module loading tricks) to have dc use v3 while other things in the page use v4. Hope to find time later in the year to [port dc.js to d3v4](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1173) but it's a big task.